# Не проходит тест на LeetCode. А в редакторе VSC проходит

Tags: python, функции, классы, visual-studio-code, инспекция-кода

Есть задача 1. Two Sum на LeetCode.
Я написал её в редакторе VSCode. В нём всё проходит. После переноса в литкод сначала выпадала ошибка: NameError: name 'Solution' is not defined...
После чего добавил class Solution. Стала выпадать ошибка: TypeError: Solution.twosome() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given...
Затем добавил self параметр при объявлении функции. Тесты прошли, но вот беда! В VSCodе такой код не работает, так как требуется ещё один аргумент для функции, что логично принципе.
Так вот вопрос: Как это работает? Эта какая-то специальная система проверки кода на LeetCode? Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить? Я просто новичок в программировании, если что прошу прощения за глупые вопросы)

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(array: list, target: int) -> list:
        for index, num in enumerate(array):
            if array[index] + array[index + 1] == target:
                return [index, index + 1]
```

Comment: На лет коде даётся заготовка для кода прототип метода. Ее нельзя изменять, в данное вам обрамление вписываете тело метода, выполняющее работу

Comment: да, я уже потом это понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно всё понял, то просто на сайте вызывают этот метод от **экземпляра класса**, а вы его пытаетесь вызывать от самого класса. Когда вызывают от экземпляра, то передаётся дополнительный параметр, в котором содержится ссылка на собственно экземпляр класса. Который обычно и называется `self` в питоне - такая договорённость. Таким образом, скорее всего вам нужно сделать так, чтобы и локально всё выполнялось корректно:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, array: list, target: int) -> list:
               ^^^^ <- обратите внимание
        for index, num in enumerate(array):
            if array[index] + array[index + 1] == target:
                return [index, index + 1]

solution = Solution()
result = solution.twoSum([1,2,3,4,5], 7)
print(result)
```

То есть нужно создать экземпляр класса и вызывать метод `twoSum` уже от него, а не прямо от самого класса.

Comment: Да. Так работает! То есть если функция объявляется через класс, для того чтобы онпа корректно отработала,  то её всегда нужно вызывать от созданного экземпляра класса?

Comment: @Denika Нет. Могут быть и методы, которым не нужно состояние класса, они объявляются без `self` и их вызывают прямо от класса. Но вообще перед ними тогда должен стоять декоратор `@staticmethod` по-хорошему. В общем, вам нужно знать, что есть два способа вызова методов класса, но как их можно вызвать должно быть предусмотрено заранее самими этими методами. Которые с `self` первым параметром, те нужно вызывать от экземпляра, а которые без - те от самого класса. Оба способа вполне легальные. Функция внутри класса правильно называется "метод", чтобы отличить от просто функций, которые сами по себе